# How do I check connection status of Modbus-TCP?

Tags: c#, connection, modbus, modbus-tcp

I've set up a Modbus-tcp slave using NModbus4 library.

I want to show the slave's status, whether it's listening(running?) or not running(idle?) - to show visually with green/red indicators.

I've looked through NModbus4 library and couldn't find any function that indicates the slave's status. Below is my best shot but it doesn't indicate if the slave stopped.

```
case "TCP":
    try
    {
        TcpListener slaveTcpListener = new TcpListener(IP, Port);
        slaveTcpListener.Start();
        slave = ModbusTcpSlave.CreateTcp(SlaveID, slaveTcpListener);
        slave.DataStore = DataStoreFactory.CreateDefaultDataStore(MaxCoil, MaxDI, MaxHR, MaxIR);
        slave.DataStore.DataStoreReadFrom += new EventHandler<DataStoreEventArgs>(dataStore_DataStoreReadFrom);
        slave.ModbusSlaveRequestReceived += Slave_ModbusSlaveRequestReceived;
        slave.Listen();

        lblCommStatus.Text = "Listening";
        btnIndicator.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    catch
    {
        // Exception Handle
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your requirement. `slave.Listen()` will block so code after that will not execute. I guess you could periodically call `slave.Masters` to see what (if anything) is connected. Note that [NModbus4](https://github.com/NModbus4/NModbus4) has had no commits since 2016 so you may want to look elsewhere (perhaps [NModbus](https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus/) which is a fork).